# Replicate Oracle into HsqlDB (and knowing what the change was)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, hsqldb

I am interested in taking an Oracle DB and "replicating" it into hsqldb - very fast, close to real time. And hopefully, also be aware of what fields were changed. (I need this in order to boost queries duration - and saw that HSQLDB in embedded in memory mode is much faster than even cached Oracle. However, since oracle grants me persistency, failover etc. I still want to use it).

So, I thought about a few possible approaches:

1. Use trigger on every possible table in my oracle db. The trigger will write the change to an auxiliary table. Very bad performance & practice, in my opion.
2. periodically select each table for all the latest updates (select * from T where ora_rowscn > ?). ?=latest maximal row scn. This has the disadvantage of not knowing about deletes (even though we can figure some other way for deletes). This also has the disadvantage of having to diff the previous record with the new record to understand the change. The table may be of 100 fields and the change on only one.
3. Use Oracle notifications, available since 11/10g - using a simple JDBC link - though this has some limitations, like: number of fields you can get that have changed.
4. Use "2" approach along with quering the sql_text table, in order to see which fields were affected in latest updates, and to diff only those from the last 1 minute. This will actually also help with figuring out deletes.
5. Use timesten instead of HSQLDB, but that costs money.

What do you think? What is the best way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should explore the existing tools, notably SymmetricDS (http://www.symmetricds.org) and see if they can be configured or modified to support this.

An alternative approach is to write the triggers in HSQLDB to update the Oracle backend when there is a data change.